# Flutter: How to change biometric authentication messages in another language?

Tags: flutter

How to change biometric authentication **failed messages**. I used flutter [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth) package.
I want to translate messages below to another language. I think these messages are coming from system and using system language. It must be in english even system language is in another language. In my case, title's text is in English, body's texts are in French. It must be in same language.
- No match.
- Keep your finger on the sensor a little longer.
- Make sure your finger covers the entire sensor.
...

[Click here to see image of biometric auth dialog.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlrMw.jpg)

```dart
final LocalAuthentication auth = LocalAuthentication();
bool authenticated = false;

try {
  authenticated = await auth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
    localizedReason: 'biometric auth for login',
    useErrorDialogs: true,
    stickyAuth: true,
    androidAuthStrings: AndroidAuthMessages(
      signInTitle: 'Fingerprint login',
      ...
    ),
    iOSAuthStrings: IOSAuthMessages(
      lockOut: 'test',
      ...
    ),
  );
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == auth_error.notAvailable) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used flutter, but by just reading the documentation:

***If you don't want to use the default dialogs***, call this API with 'useErrorDialogs = false'. In this case, it will throw the error message back and you need to handle them in your dart code:

```
bool didAuthenticate =
    await localAuth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
        localizedReason: 'Please authenticate to show account balance',
        useErrorDialogs: false);
```

*You can use our default dialog messages, or you can use your own messages by passing in IOSAuthMessages and AndroidAuthMessages:*

```
import 'package:local_auth/auth_strings.dart';

const iosStrings = const IOSAuthMessages(
    cancelButton: 'cancel',
    goToSettingsButton: 'settings',
    goToSettingsDescription: 'Please set up your Touch ID.',
    lockOut: 'Please reenable your Touch ID');
await localAuth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
    localizedReason: 'Please authenticate to show account balance',
    useErrorDialogs: false,
    iOSAuthStrings: iosStrings);
```

Exceptions

*There are 6 types of exceptions: PasscodeNotSet, NotEnrolled, NotAvailable, OtherOperatingSystem, LockedOut and PermanentlyLockedOut. They are wrapped in LocalAuthenticationError class. You can catch the exception and handle them by different types. For example:*

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:local_auth/error_codes.dart' as auth_error;

try {
  bool didAuthenticate = await local_auth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
      localizedReason: 'Please authenticate to show account balance');
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == auth_error.notAvailable) {
    // Handle this exception here.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but useErrorDialogs shows different dialog. I want to change main bottom sheet dialog's messages.

Comment: I want to change messages such as 'No match', 'Keep your finger on the sensor a little longer.', 'Make sure your finger covers the entire sensor'.

Comment: I disabled useErrorDialogs, but PlatformException doesn't catch the errors. There are a few error codes.

Comment: These messages, as you said, I believe come from system. If that's true, there's not a way to change them.

Comment: You could try and use something like the Intl package to localize your string messages, and then pass those in as the value for 'localizedReason'. 
https://pub.dev/packages/intl

Comment: this is not working